# Stacking polymorphism

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I have the following structure of types:

```
-- 'root':
data Skill a = Skill {rate :: a, spawns :: Actor a}
  deriving (Show, Read, Functor)

data Actor a = Area {appl :: Actor a, radius :: a}
             | Projectile {appl :: Actor a, speed :: a, projDuration :: Double}
             | Hit [Effect a]
  deriving (Show, Read, Functor)

data Effect a = Damage [(a, a, Tag)]
         --   | ...      
  deriving (Show, Read, Functor)
```

These types are the most intuitive description of the idea for me (`a` would simply be a `Num` type most of the time). My problem now is that every one of these types also has `Properties` and that i want to apply a function `eval :: Properties -> a -> b` to all `a` in the data structure using all `Properties` along the way.

```
-- for example
data Skill a = Skill {props :: Properties, rate :: a, ...}
data Actor a = Area {props :: Properties, appl :: ...}
```

These `Properties` have little to do with the actual structure and can be applied to anything. To me this sounds like i should have:

```
Prop a = Prop Properties a
```

I tried using `StateT`to hold and distribute properties over a simpler tree(all types summed up in one...) but that made working with the structure 'unpleasant'. I could just make a type class for `eval` but that feels wrong because the instances would merely pass the properties along.
My goal here is to separate the structure described by Skill/Actor/... from the behavior of Properties so that changing either won't require changing code related to the other, but i don't really know which tool to reach for or if i'm making this more complicated than it needs to be.

(Feel free to change the title if you can identify what i'm struggling with here...)

Edit: (this would be a lot of code to set up...)
given `data Properties = [Int]`, 
an element `a` in an `Effect` with (properties) `[6]` 
in an `Actor` with `[10]` 
in a `Skill` with `[1,3]` 
would have to be evaluated with the entire list `[1,3,10,6]`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're currently trying, but it sounds like you have `Properties` in your `deriving Functor` types, right? You could use `newtype Prop a = Prop Properties` and then create its forgetful `Functor` instance.

Comment: @Zeta Yes, i want to 'extend' the deriving Functor types by data (Properties) and behavior and end up with an 'improved Functor'. I don't know what you mean by 'forgetful Functor', though. An evaluation of an element in `Actor a` would take Properties of the parent (`Skill`) and the 'node' `Actor` itself.